# Is there an alternative way to span three displays when using a Nvidia Graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Thanks for looking!

## Background

I have a four monitor set up at home with three monitors in a row and then a fourth monitor directly below the middle monitor.

On the weekends, I have a *brief* window of time to play a flight sim or game to blow off some steam and when I do that, I usually turn off the fourth monitor and span the three displays so I have one big 5760 X 1080 display.

## The Problem

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 670 and the software provided by Nvidia for spanning displays is clunky, doesn't remember my settings, completely screws up all of the settings I had before going to surround mode once I go back to standard mode, etc.  In summary, it is slow and aggravating and wheedles down that precious hour per week I have to play a game by at least 10 minutes--not cool!

## Question

Is there a better way to toggle between three 1920 X 1080 monitors and one spanned 5760 X 1080 monitor config?  Perhaps a third party plug in someone has written?

I used to be able to switch to projector mode (natively in Windows) and somehow it worked but this was a couple of PCs ago, though I was using a Nvidia card then as well.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use a piece of software called [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) to manage multiple monitor profiles. It can save and restore preset configurations, including spanning and even virtual sub-monitor splits. It also has window management features that I find very useful.

I am in no way affiliated with the publisher, Binary Fortress, other than being a customer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am trying DisplayFusion now, though not having the easy success I hoped for.  I will report back when I get it cracked.  Thanks again!